# PHP wrapper around an API - best practices

Tags: php, unit-testing, api, wrapper, mocks

Here's a PHP wrapper around a public OAuth2 REST API. I would love to hear your thoughts and comments. Testing was a bit frustrating since I tried for my first time. Not sure if I have done the mocking properly.

You can see the whole project on [Github](https://github.com/stakisko/feedly-api)

```
class Feedly {
    private
        $_apiBaseUrl = "https://cloud.feedly.com",
        $_authorizePath = "/v3/auth/auth",
        $_accessTokenPath = "/v3/auth/token",
        $_storeAccessTokenToSession;

    /**
     * @param boolean $sandbox                   Enable/Disable Sandbox Mode
     * @param boolean $storeAccessTokenToSession Choose whether to store the Access token
     *                                           to $_SESSION or not
     */
    public function __construct($sandbox=FALSE, $storeAccessTokenToSession=TRUE) {
        $this->_storeAccessTokenToSession = $storeAccessTokenToSession;
        if($this->_storeAccessTokenToSession) session_start();
        if($sandbox) $this->_apiBaseUrl = "https://sandbox.feedly.com";
    }

    /**
     * Return authorization URL
     * @param string $client_id     Client's ID provided by Feedly's Administrators
     * @param string $redirect_uri  Endpoint to reroute with the results
     * @param string $response_type
     * @param string $scope
     *
     * @return string Authorization URL
     */
    public function getLoginUrl ($client_id, $redirect_uri,
        $response_type="code", $scope="https://cloud.feedly.com/subscriptions") {

        return($this->_apiBaseUrl . $this->_authorizePath . "?" .
            http_build_query(array(
                "client_id"=>$client_id,
                "redirect_uri"=>$redirect_uri,
                "response_type"=>$response_type,
                "scope"=>$scope
                )
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Exchange a `code` got from `getLoginUrl` for an `Access Token`
     * @param string $client_id     Client's ID provided by Feedly's Administrators
     * @param string $client_secret Client's Secret provided by Feedly's Administrators
     * @param string $auth_code     Code obtained from `getLoginUrl`
     * @param string $redirect_url  Endpoint to reroute with the results
     */
    public function GetAccessToken($client_id, $client_secret, $auth_code,
        $redirect_url) {

        $r = null;
        if (($r = @curl_init($this->_apiBaseUrl . $this->_accessTokenPath)) == false) {
            throw new Exception("Cannot initialize cUrl session.
                Is cUrl enabled for your PHP installation?");
        }

        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 1);

        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\cacert.crt");

        // Add client ID and client secret to the headers.
        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
            "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($client_id . ":" .
                $client_secret),
        ));

        $post_fields = "code=" . urlencode($auth_code) .
            "&client_id=" . urlencode($client_id) .
            "&client_secret=" . urlencode($client_secret) .
            "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_url) .
            "&grant_type=authorization_code";

        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);

        $response = curl_exec($r);
        $http_status = curl_getinfo($r, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $tmpr = json_decode($response, true);
        curl_close($r);

        if($http_status!==200)
            throw new Exception("Response from API: " . $tmpr['errorMessage']);

        if($this->_storeAccessTokenToSession){
            if(!isset($_SESSION['access_token'])){
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $tmpr['access_token'];
                session_write_close();
            }
        }

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * cUrl Initiliazation
     * @param string $url   URL to query
     * @param string $token Access Token in case we don't store it to $_SESSION
     */
    private function InitCurl($url, $token=NULL) {
        $r = null;

        if (($r = @curl_init($url)) == false) {
            throw new Exception("Cannot initialize cUrl session.
                Is cUrl enabled for your PHP installation?");
        }

        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 1);

        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\cacert.crt");

        $access_token = is_null($token) ? $this->_getAccessTokenFromSession() : $token;
        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
            "Authorization: OAuth " . $access_token
        ));

        return($r);
    }

    /**
     * Query a URL with GET using cUrl after initialization
     * @param string $url        URL to query
     * @param string $get_params Parameters to pass to URL as GET params
     * @param string $token      Access Token in case we don't store it to $_SESSION
     */
    public function ExecGetRequest($url, $get_params=NULL, $token=NULL) {
        $url = $this->_apiBaseUrl . $url;

        if(is_array($get_params))
            $r = $this->InitCurl($url .'?',
                http_build_query($url, $get_params), $token);
        else
            $r = $this->InitCurl($url, $token);

        $response = curl_exec($r);
        if ($response == false) {
            die("curl_exec() failed. Error: " . curl_error($r));
        }

        $http_status = curl_getinfo($r, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $tmpr = json_decode($response, true);
        curl_close($r);

        if($http_status!==200)
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong: " . $tmpr['errorMessage']);
        else
            return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Make a POST request
     * @param string $url        URL to query
     * @param string $get_params Parameters to pass to URL as GET params
     * @param string $post_params Parameters to pass to URL as POST params
     * @param string $token      Access Token in case we don't store it to $_SESSION
     */
    public function ExecPostRequest($url, $get_params=NULL, $post_params=NULL, $token=NULL) {
        $url = $this->_apiBaseUrl . $url;

        if(is_array($get_params))
            $r = $this->InitCurl($url .'?',
                http_build_query($url, $get_params), $token);
        else
            $r = $this->InitCurl($url, $token);

        $post_fields = http_build_query($post_params);

        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);

        $response = curl_exec($r);
        if ($response == false) {
            die("curl_exec() failed. Error: " . curl_error($r));
        }

        $http_status = curl_getinfo($r, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $tmpr = json_decode($response, true);
        curl_close($r);

        if($http_status!==200)
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong: " . $tmpr['errorMessage']);
        else
            return $response;
    }

    /**
     * @see http://developer.feedly.com/v3/profile/#get-the-profile-of-the-user
     * @param string $token Access Token in case we don't store it to $_SESSION
     * @return json Response from the server
     */
    public function getProfile($token=NULL) {
        return $this->ExecGetRequest('/v3/profile', NULL, $token);
    }

    /**
     * @see http://developer.feedly.com/v3/profile/#update-the-profile-of-the-user
     * @param string $email
     * @param string $givenName
     * @param string $familyName
     * @param string $picture
     * @param boolean $gender
     * @param string $locale
     * @param string $reader google reader id
     * @param string $twitter twitter handle. example: edwk
     * @param string $facebook facebook id
     * @param  string $token Access Token in case we don't store it to $_SESSION
     * @return json Response from the server
     */
    public function setProfile($token=NULL, $email=NULL, $givenName=NULL, $familyName=NULL,
        $picture=NULL, $gender=NULL, $locale=NULL,
        $reader=NULL, $twitter=NULL, $facebook=NULL) {
        return $this->ExecPostRequest('/v3/profile', NULL, array(
            'email'=>$email,
            'givenName'=>$givenName,
            'familyName'=>$familyName,
            'picture'=>$picture,
            'gender'=>$gender,
            'locale'=>$locale,
            'reader'=>$reader,
            'twitter'=>$twitter,
            'facebook'=>$facebook
        ), $token);
    }

    /**
     * @see http://developer.feedly.com/v3/preferences/#get-the-preferences-of-the-user
     * @param  string $token Access Token in case we don't store it to $_SESSION
     * @return json   Response from the server
     */
    public function getPreferences($token=NULL) {
        return $this->ExecGetRequest('/v3/preferences', NULL, $token);
    }

    /* More code happens here, check the full version 
    *https://github.com/stakisko/feedly-api/blob/master/feedly.php 
    */

    /**
     * @return string Access Token from $_SESSION
     */
    protected function _getAccessTokenFromSession(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['access_token'])){
            return $_SESSION['access_token'];
        }else {
            throw new Exception("No access token", 1);
        }
    }
}


<?php

include_once './feedly.php';
include_once './vendor/autoload.php';

class FeedlyAPITest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $instance;

    function __construct(){
        ini_set("session.use_cookies", 0);
        $this->instance = new Feedly(true, false);
    }

    /**
     * Test valid returned URL for authorization
     */
    public function testGetLoginURL()
    {
        $this->assertNotEmpty($this->instance->getLoginUrl("sandbox", "http://localhost"));
    }

    /**
     * Testing GetAccessToken on failure
     * will throw exception
     */
    public function testGetAccessTokenThrowsExceptionOnFailure()
    {
        try {
            $this->instance->GetAccessToken();
        } catch (Exception $expected) {
            return;
        }

        $this->fail();
    }

    /**
     * Testing GetAccessToken
     */
    public function testGetAccessToken()
    {
        $json = '
        {
          "access_token": 1385150462,
          "stuff": {
            "this": 2,
            "that": 4,
            "other": 1
            }
        } ';

        $feedly = $this->getMock('Feedly', array('GetAccessToken'), array(true, false));

        $feedly->expects($this->any())
             ->method('GetAccessToken')
             ->will($this->returnValue($json));

        $this->assertEquals($json, $feedly->GetAccessToken("sandbox", "FUFNPXDNP2J0BF7RCEUZ", "", "http://localhost"));
    }

    /**
     * Testing a GET Request to API without providing an Access Token
     * will throw exception
     */
    public function testExecGetRequestWithoutAccessTokenThrowsException(){
        try {
            $this->instance->ExecGetRequest('/v3/profile');
        } catch (Exception $expected) {
            return;
        }

        $this->fail();
    }

    /**
     * Testing a GET Request to API
     */
    public function testExecGetRequest(){
        $json = '
        {
          "access_token": 1385150462,
          "stuff": {
            "this": 2,
            "that": 4,
            "other": 1
            }
        } ';

        $feedly = $this->getMock('Feedly', array('ExecGetRequest'), array(true, false));

        $feedly->expects($this->any())
             ->method('ExecGetRequest')
             ->will($this->returnValue($json));

        $this->assertEquals($json, $feedly->ExecGetRequest("/dum/url"));
    }

    /**
     * Testing a POST Request to API
     */
    public function testExecPostRequest(){
        $json = '
        {
          "access_token": 1385150462,
          "stuff": {
            "this": 2,
            "that": 4,
            "other": 1
            }
        } ';

        $feedly = $this->getMock('Feedly', array('ExecPostRequest'), array(true, false));

        $feedly->expects($this->any())
             ->method('ExecPostRequest')
             ->will($this->returnValue($json));

        $this->assertEquals($json, $feedly->ExecPostRequest('/dummy/url', NULL, array(
            'email'=>'odysseus@ithaka.gr',
            'givenName'=>''
        )));
    }
}
```

Comment: _Please_, __Please__ subscribe to the, as of yet, unofficial coding standards [as described here](http://www.php-fig.org/). The more people adopt these, the better. Symfony, Zend, Doctrine, PEAR,... all subscribe to these conventions

Answer (score 4):

Two minor notes:

1. The following is not too easy to read:

   ```
   curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 1);
   ```

   Readers have to be really familar with curl parameters or have to check the documentation. It [says the following](http://hu1.php.net/curl_setopt):

   > The contents of the "Accept-Encoding: " header. This enables decoding
   >   of the response. Supported encodings are "identity", "deflate", and "gzip". 
   >   If an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all supported encoding 
   >   types is sent.

   But it's `1`, which isn't a string. `1 == ""`? I suggest the following:

   ```
   curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_ENCODING, ALL_SUPPORTED_ENCODING_TYPES);
   ```

   where `ALL_SUPPORTED_ENCODING_TYPES` is a constant with an empty string value. (I suppose `1 == ""`.)
2. Comments like this is unnecessary:

   ```
   /**
    * Testing GetAccessToken
    */
   public function testGetAccessToken()
   ```

   The function name says the same, so I'd remove the comment. In the following case I'd rename the function to `testValidReturnedUrlForAuthorization()` and remove the comment:

   ```
    /**
    * Test valid returned URL for authorization
    */
   public function testGetLoginURL()
   ```

   (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*: *Chapter 4: Comments, Noise Comments*)

Comment: You have absolutely right. I ve missed that! Fixed. Thank you.